# Cannot deserialize JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type List`1[JiraReporter.search]' type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json, serialization

I have jSON like below:

```
{
"expand": "names,schema",
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 50,
"total": 1,
"issues": [
    {
        "expand": "",
        "id": "10001",
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/10001",
        "key": "HSP-1"
    }
]
```

For the above, I have class like below:

```
[DataContract]
public class Issue
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string expand { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string self { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string key { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class search
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string expand { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int startAt { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public int total { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public IList<Issue> issues { get; set; }
}
```

trying to deserialize the above json using below code:

```
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<search>>(strsearchlist);
```

However, I'm getting error as below:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JiraReporter.search]' 
because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type 
e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
 JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path 'expand', line 1, position 10.

This is my method return type : >  //search is enum

I'm using newton json lib.
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your text lost the last `}`
- your json is against `search` ,not `List<search>`

so,the code must be like below

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<search>(strsearchlist);
return result;
//return new List<search>(){result};//if you want to return List,you can use this
```

Comment: Big Thanks. Not getting error. However, need to check, how much it can be useful to the existing scenario.